# Android app to get Bokeh effect for portraits on single camera lens?

Tags: android, camera

I tried apps like `Snapseed` which helps to blur the background and give bokeh effect.
but it's manual,

so, Is there any app, based on AI, which can automatically filters face-edges and blurs the background, on its own?

Comment: Google's camera2api, is a free, Opensource app which is exported for other devices. it is made by Google for pixel3 but XDA devs made it available to all. thanks to XDA. but it is only available for Android phones running Pie_9.0 version.